# How do I selectively augment subsets of data based on their labels?

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning, keras

I'm working on a regression neural network using Keras 1.2.1, tensorflow backend, and generators for on-the-fly image augmentation.

I want to augment my shuffled dataset, based on the labels associated with each image.

For example, at each epoch, I only want to include, say 25%, of the images that are labeled as `0.00`.
On the other hand, if the image is labeled as, say <= `-.20` I want to rotate/flip/sheer it by some random amount.

The question is, how can I choose, selectively, to augment image data based on it's label ?
Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in numpy using boolean indexing. Tensorflow also lets you do that, see [tf.boolean_mask](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask)